# Wrong Version Mongodb reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, asp.net-core, project.json

I've a asp.vnext project with dnx 4.6 . in the `project.json` i added the MongoDb Driver.

IT seems like it is working but the visual studio gives me the warning

> Depedency specified was MongoDB.Driver >= 2.1.0 ended up with
>   MongoDb.Driver 1.0.3744.30075

Looking at the packages via nuget windows i can see that 2.10 is the current version.

What am I doing wrong ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After I installed a package, I saw a correct version in `project.json` but under References a previous version was displayed. When I checked out the path for that old reference, I realized Visual Studio uses an older version from global packages storage (in my case `C:\Users\{username}\.dnx\packages\Ninject\3.0.1.10`). So I removed and old version from global packages storage and that's it. Seems like Microsoft has reinvented DLL hell.